# How to loop print output and write each result to csv?

Tags: python, loops, csv, random, output

I have written the following code to generate a random 12 number string:

```
import uuid

def my_random_string(string_length=12):
    """Returns a random string of length string_length."""
    random = str(uuid.uuid4()) # Convert UUID format to a Python string.
    random = random.upper() # Make all characters uppercase.
    random = random.replace("-","") # Remove the UUID '-'.
    return random[0:string_length] # Return the random string.

print(my_random_string(12)) # For example, D9E50Cd
```

How can I loop it and save each string output to a .csv file?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: A CSV format file consisting of one value per row has no separator characters in it and can be created by simply writing each string value plus a newline character into a text file opened in write mode. You'll also need to call your function inside the loop to get a different random value each iteration of the loop.

Comment: how you expect the output ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will output random strings (using the code you provided) to a CSV file.

```
import csv
import uuid

def my_random_string(string_length=12):
    """Returns a random string of length string_length."""
    random = str(uuid.uuid4()) # Convert UUID format to a Python string.
    random = random.upper() # Make all characters uppercase.
    random = random.replace("-","") # Remove the UUID '-'.
    return random[0:string_length] # Return the random string.

def random_string_to_csv(file_name, column_header, num_rows):
    num_cols = len(column_header)
    with open(file_name, mode='w', newline = '') as f:
        rand_string_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        rand_string_writer.writerow(column_header)
        for i in range(num_rows):
            row = [my_random_string() for j in range(num_cols)]
            rand_string_writer.writerow(row)

column_header = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
num_rows = 5
random_string_to_csv('test.csv', column_header, num_rows)
```

CSV files often have column headers, so I included that in the code example. You could easily change the function definition to exclude a column header and explicitly define the number of columns when the function is called, like this:

```
def random_string_to_csv(file_name, num_cols, num_rows):
    with open(file_name, mode='w', newline = '') as f:
        rand_string_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for i in range(num_rows):
            row = [my_random_string() for j in range(num_cols)]
            rand_string_writer.writerow(row)
```